# MD5 value of upload file

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to extract MD5 and length (size) of the upload blob using Azure function using Http Trigger, Below the code im experimenting, but I always get null and -1. Please someone confirm the code is correct  or any other option is available

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req,string inputBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];
    log.LogInformation($"name,{inputBlob}");
    log.LogInformation("Blob content: " + inputBlob.Properties.Length); //This is printing content of blob


    CloudBlockBlob blob;
   var credentials = new StorageCredentials("xxx", "xxxx");
   var client = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri("https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net"), credentials);
    var container = client.GetContainerReference("parent");
    blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.csv");
    log.LogInformation("Blob details: " + blob.Properties.Length); //This is printing -1, if i provide ContentMD5 its showing null. Bascially its not able to read the blob 



    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Comment: If the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `FetchAttributesAsync()` (or `FetchAttributes()`) method before you try to retrieve any properties of the blob.

```
//your other code
blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.csv");
blob.FetchAttributesAsync()(); //or FetchAttributes()

//then you can try to get any property here.
```

Comment: I tried using above method ,but it throwed BLOB API can be used. I was trying to get the attributes of the blob from ADLS Gen2, seems the blob api not supported. Any idea of how to get the md5 of the file stored on ADLS Gen2 ?

Comment: @sathishkumarkandhaswamy, can you take a look at [Azure Data Lake Store Gen2 REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/data-lake-storage-gen2)? If you have any issues, please let me know.

Comment: @sathishkumarkandhaswamy, I give an example of how to use the Gen2 rest api on how to get these properties, in your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623543/how-to-get-md5-of-file-stored-in-adls-gen2/55686684#55686684)