# How to get MD5 of file stored in ADLS Gen2?

Tags: azure

I receive daily files through sFTP to ADLS gen 2 storage account. I need to verify the file by checking the MD5 of the file stored in ADLS gen2.

I tried using the BLOB API , currently its not supporting ADLS gen2. I was able to get Content MD5 from blob properties if the file is stored in Blob storage.

Can someone help how to get the content MD5 from ADLS gen 2?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Blob api is not supported as you know, but you can take a look at `Data Lake Storage Gen2 rest api` -> [Path - Get Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/getproperties), which can be used to fetch properties of files stored in ADLS Gen2.

Here is a sample code(Note that I use the sas token appended to the api url):

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sasToken = "?sv=2018-03-28&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdl&st=2019-04-15T08%3A07%3A49Z&se=2019-04-16T08%3A07%3A49Z&sig=xxxx";
            string url = "https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/myfilesys1/app.JPG" + sasToken;
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(url));
            req.Method = "HEAD";
            var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("the status code is: "+res.StatusCode);

            var headers = res.Headers;
            Console.WriteLine("the count of the headers is: "+headers.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("*********");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //list all the properties if you don't know which correct format of property.
            foreach (var h in headers.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(h.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("*********");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //take the Content-Type property for example.
            var myheader = res.GetResponseHeader("Content-Type");
            Console.WriteLine($"the header Content-Type is: {myheader}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you don't know how to generate sas token, you can nav to azure portal -> your storage account, then follow the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: In the example, I take the "Content-Type" property for example. You can change it to MD5. And please let me know if it works or not.